# How can I get the most popular phrases from a lot of text?

Tags: php

I'm setting up a Twitter-style "trending topics" box for my forum. I've got the most popular /words/, but can't even begin to think how I will get popular phrases, like Twitter does.

As it stands I just get all the content of the last 200 posts into a string and split them into words, then sort by which words are used the most. How can I turn this from most popular words into the most popular phrases?

Comment: Really depends on what you are going to define as a "phrase"

Comment: How about glueing two/three/four words together to one? It would still be O(n).

Comment: i don't think that you'll find your answer on a few code lines on stackoverflow.. this problem is a thesis subject probably related to web semantics

Comment: @pleasedontbelong While I don't think this is an NP-complete problem, it certainly isn't all that complex to perform a simple "brute force" analysis on a block of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique you might consider is the use of ZSETs in Redis for something like this. If you've got very large sets of data, you'll find that you can do something like this:

```
$words = explode(" ", $input); // Pseudo-code for breaking a block of data into individual words.
$word_count = count($words);

$r = new Redis(); // Owlient's PHPRedis PECL extension
$r->connect("127.0.0.1", 6379);

function process_phrase($phrase) {
    global $r;
    $phrase = implode(" ", $phrase);
    $r->zIncrBy("trending_phrases", 1, $phrase);
}

for($i=0;$i<$word_count;$i++)
    for($j=1;$j<$word_count - $i;$j++)
        process_phrase(array_slice($words, $i, $j));
```

To retrieve the top phrases, you'd use this:

```
// Assume $r is instantiated like it is above
$trending_phrases = $r->zReverseRange("trending_phrases", 0, 10);
```

`$trending_phrases` will be an array of the top ten trending phrases. To do things like recent trending phrases (as opposed to a persistent, global set of phrases), duplicate all of the Redis interactions above. For each interaction, use a key that's indicative of, say, today's timestamp and tomorrow's timestamp (i.e.: days since Jan 1, 1970). When retrieving the results with `$trending_phrases`, just retrieve both today and tomorrow's (or yesterday's) key and use `array_merge` and `array_unique` to find the union.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting individual words split individual phrases, it's as simple as that.

```
$popular = array();

foreach ($tweets as $tweet)
{
    // split by common punctuation chars
    $sentences = preg_split('~[.!?]+~', $string);

    foreach ($sentences as $sentence)
    {
        $sentence = strtolower(trim($sentence)); // normalize sentences

        if (isset($popular[$sentence]) === false)  
        //if (array_key_exists($sentence, $popular) === false)
        {
            $popular[$sentence] = 0;
        }

        $popular[$sentence]++;
    }
}

arsort($popular);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($popular);
echo '</pre>';
```

It'll be a lot slower if you consider a phrase as an aggregation of *n* consecutive words.

Comment: As a matter of performance, `array_key_exists($sentence, $popular) !== true` is a whole order of magnitude slower than `!isset($popular[$sentence])`. In this situation, the functional differences are unimportant.

Comment: @mattbasta: Indeed. But, an order of magnitude slower? As in 10x slower? Do you have any benchmark that shows these results?

Comment: I don't have any handy, but I've had experience with larger arrays (1000+ elements) that `isset` will take within 50ms, `array_key_exists` can take up to 300-400ms.

Comment: @mattbasta: I believe that was an old issue and although `isset()` is still faster than `array_key_exists()` the difference isn't that noticeable. Anyway, I'll run some benchmarks when I get home.

Comment: I ran a benchmark of my own; it seems (as you said) that with newer versions of PHP, this isn't so much of an issue. `array_key_exists` is about 20% slower, but that only really equates out to about 10ms in some of the more extreme cases.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what type of answer you were looking for but Laconica:

http://status.net/?source=laconica

Is an open source twitter clone (a much simpler version).

Maybe you could use part of the code to make your own popular frases?

Good luck!